# Making an autoresponder in php

Tags: php, auto-responder

I have a website that has a contact form. And when someone uses it I receive the message. But I would like to set up an autoresponder to inform the person who contacted me that their message has been received etc.

Code:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('admin/data/contact.txt'));
    include('includes/header.php');
    if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])) {
        $to = $settings->email;
        $subject = 'Contact from Website';
        $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']) . "\r\n";
        //$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $message = "Hi, A message from contact form.";
        $message .= "<br /><br /><br />Name: ".$_REQUEST['name'];
        $message .= "<br />Email: ".$_REQUEST['email'];
        $message .= "<br />Subject: ".$_REQUEST['subject'];
        $message .= "<br />Message: ".$_REQUEST['message'];
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        $msg = 'Your Message has been sent. Thank You.';
    }
    $btn = '<input type="submit" style="font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; height: auto; color: #fff; border-radius: 15px; border: none;" class="btn_new" value="SEND" />';
?>
```

How can I edit this code in order to set this up?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
....
....
$message .= "<br />Message: ".$_REQUEST['message'];
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
  echo "Mail Sent Successfully";      
  //Send autoresponder email to $_REQUEST['email'];
  //inform the person who contacted me that their message has been received etc.

}
  else
{
  echo "Mail Not Sent";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is on the right track, but what happens is the email arrives in my email instead of being sent to the person that used the contact form. So I get, for example, "from: somemail@mail.com" and "to: support@mysite.com". But what I want is for the email to get sent to the person that contacted me. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: I hope I added the code you sent me in the correct place. I added it below "$msg = 'Your Message has been sent. Thank You.';" and above the bracket.

Comment: I think the problem is the $to in the code you've given me. As far as I understand it, I don't want the email sent to $to (because that's me), I want the email sent to "$message .= "<br />Email: ".$_REQUEST['email'];" (because that's where the person who uses the contact form will submit their email address.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. I removed this bit - $message .= "<br />Message: ".$_REQUEST['message']; - and I changed this bit - if(@mail($_REQUEST['email']... - and now it works. I mean, the email goes to Spam, but I don't think that's related, right?

Comment: Okay, I've been playing around with this ever since you replied, and I managed to make it exactly how I wanted :) I will mark your answer as correct, because it's what set me on the right path to figuring this out. Thank you very much :)